# Chrome won't launch installed app

Tags: google-chrome, protocols

I have multiple apps that are installed via web browser.
I can later launch all apps from a link using this

```
location.href = appname://launch:00/
```

However when I have this,
`location.href = 5appname://launch:00/`, it breaks and gives "invalid URL" errors.

The same method works in IE, just chrome is breaking,
if I try `//5appname://launch:00/` I lose the console error but the app doesn't launch

I know the number in the start is the issue.

I can't really change app names. Any way to get this to work

Comment: *What* errors? You should always quote them in full, even if you think paraphrasing is sufficient (which is not always the case).

Comment: Hi my apologies it says "Invalid Url"